# Allow admin to merge without pull requestion approval on github protected branch

Tags: github, github-actions

I believe this is a slight variant of [this question.](https://github.community/t/how-to-allow-maintainers-to-merge-without-required-approvals/116601)

I'm the admin of a project and also (almost) sole developer but am adding collaborators. I have gitflow actions/workflows for automated testing. For myself (admin), I want this behavior in protected master:

- All status checks must pass
- Pull request review approvals are *not* required

Whereas for everyone else:

- All status checks must pass
- Pull request review approvals *are* required

Setting up required PR approval and required status checks works except it requires the admin to also get PR approval. If I exclude the admins from the branch protection it applies globally, so it allows merging without PR approval but also allows merging without passing status checks, which is not what I want.

Comment: There is an auto-merge action (https://github.com/pascalgn/automerge-action), that could be used, adding a conditional at the step that would merge it only for your github username (`if: github.actor == '<username>'`). Note that this auto-merge option is now available directly on Github GUI (https://docs.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/automatically-merging-a-pull-request). I guess using the action can be an alternative way to customize it (I personnaly use it with hmarr/auto-approve-action as well to approve depending on the github PR autor before merging).